# Attaching default image on Choose FIle

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, input

I've been looking and struggling to find the answer how to attach a default image on "Choose File" using JS/Jquery. My goal is if the user forgot to attach an image, I want to have some image url on default. So that if the user clicks the submit button, that default image will be uploaded instead. I know this is inefficient way to do this, I just want to know how you can manipulate the file that is being uploaded.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="file"/>
        <input type="submit">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: just check for an image existence, if an image is present(the user has selected an image) submit the form, otherwise, prevent submission and give the user some clarification of what's happening(tell him to select an image for example).

Comment: That's why I said "I know this is inefficient way to do this." Because I am already aware of it. I need it for different purpose.

Comment: for security reasons, you can't make a default value for an input type file. Maybe you can try, in the back-end script you can check for the existence of an image, if it's not present just grab one from the net.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener for the submit button, and first check if user selected any file

```
<input id="get-file" type="file">
<input id="submit-file" type="submit">
<script>

const inputField = document.querySelector('#get-file');
const submitButton  = document.querySelector('#submit-file');

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // This is where you check whether user uploaded a file or not
  if (!inputField.value) {
    // Operate on the default file if user doesn't provide any

    // Make sure you exit the function
    return;
  }
  // User uploaded a file so operate on it here
});
</script>
```

Comment: The part I am really interested is where you said "// Operate on the default file if user doesn't provide any" that's they only part I need. And you didnt provide it.

Comment: But I don't know what you are going to do with the image, you just asked if you can use a default image.